# How to get a div with 100% to fully cover the width of the page with meta viewport "width=device-width"

Tags: html, css, viewport, meta

So I'm trying to make my website adjust for mobile browsers. I've got 2 CSS files, one which is always included and one with

```
media="screen and (max-width:500px)"
```

To get that to work, I'm using the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

This works great sa long the content-wrapping divs have a fixed width, or if the screen is less than 500px wide. But when I flip my phone (and thereby get >500px width), divs directly in the body with their width set to 100% get cut off. I'm assuming because width=device-width makes css 100% equal to the screen width, even if the website is larger than the screen.

**Proper in a desktop browser (the background is meant to cover the entire document width):**

[image: Proper in desktop browsers]

**In (flipped) phone or chrome mobile emulation. A large chunk of the menu cuts out.**

[image: Issue]

CSS:

```
#top{
    position:relative;
    background:rgba(191,186,130,1);
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Is there any way I can make the div width span the entire document? Do I need javascript to detect this?

Comment: The problem is another...can you ad an link?

Answer (score 0):

Set your initial scale equal to 1.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```